# purpose of SAMLContextProvider in Spring SAML

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I am trying to understand the flow of sending and receiving Authentication requests in Spring SAML. I noticed that at many points during the process the bean SAMLContextProvider is used. What is its purpose? Can the process work without it?

This bean is referenced on securityContext.xml as:

```
 <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The class SAMLContextProviderImpl is one of the important class which plays major role in spring SAML... It  decodes and encodes SAML request/response and converts the way spring can understand it. It also makes spring to understand  entityId, role, metadata, security keys of an local entity/application ...

> Context provider populates information about the local service
>   provider (your application) such as entityId, role, metadata, security
>   keys, SSL credentials and trust engines for verification of signatures
>   and SSL/TLS connections. Once populated context is made available to
>   all components participating in processing of the incoming or outgoing
>   SAML messages. ContextProvider can customized to alter behavior of the
>   SAML Extension. The default implementation
>   org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl
>   relies on information available in the ExtendedMetadata and performs
>   the following steps for creation of the context:

- Locate entityId of the local SP by parsing part of the URL after /alias/ (e.g. myAlias in https://www.myserver.com/saml_extension/saml/sso/alias/myAlias?idp=myIdp) and matching it with property alias specified in the ExtendedMetadata. In case the URL doesn't contain any alias part the default service provider configured with property hostedSPName on the metadata bean is used.
- Populate credential used to decrypt data sent to this service provider. In case ExtendedMetadata specifies property encryptionKey it will be used as an alias to lookup a private key from the keyManager bean. Otherwise defaultKey of the keyManager bean will be used.
- Populate credential used for SSL/TLS client authentication. In case ExtendedMetadata specifies property tlsKey it will be used as an alias to lookup key from keyManager bean. Otherwise no credential will be provided for client authentication.
- Populate trust engine for verification of signatures. Depending on securityProfile setting in the ExtendedMetadata trust engine based on either Section 8.2.1, “Metadata interoperability profile (MetaIOP)” or Section 8.2.2, “PKIX profile” is created.
  Populate trust engine for verification of SSL/TLS connections. Depending on sslSecurityProfile setting in the ExtendedMetadata trust engine based on either Section 8.2.1, “Metadata interoperability profile (MetaIOP)” or Section 8.2.2, “PKIX profile” is created.
  During initialization of SSO ContextProvider is also requested to provide metadata of the peer IDP. System performs these steps to locate peer IDP to use:

During initialization of SSO ContextProvider is also requested to provide metadata of the peer IDP. System performs these steps to locate peer IDP to use:

- Load parameter idp of the HttpRequest object and try to locate peer IDP by the entityId. When there's no idp parameter provided system will either start IDP discovery process (when enabled in the ExtendedMetadata of the local SP) or use the default IDP specified in the metadata bean.

Reference :  Refer the section 10.2 Context Provider of Spring SAML Doc.
[Spring SAML Doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/)

[Implementation Doc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/context/SAMLContextProviderImpl.java)